# PHP substring count function

Tags: php

I need to count the number of keyword appearances in a paragraph using php function, have the following code but it won't run so I must be missing something.

EDIT: I have changed to function to the following based on some feedback here:

```
 <?php

 function keyword_count( $paragraph, $word)
{
     $count = substr_count($paragraph, $word);
     return count;
}

?>
```

I have the following test set up:

```
<?php 

$paragraph='This is a test one two three test';
$word='test'
$expect=2;

$answer=add($paragraph, $word);

echo "Test result; ".$paragraph."+".$word."=".$answer." (expected: ".$expect.")\n";

if ($answer==$expect)
{
    echo "Test passed\n";
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    echo "Test failed\n";
    exit(1);
}
?>
```

and getting the error: substr_count(): Empty substring in **/var/www/html/functions.inc.php** on line **5**
{"error":false,"string":"+=","answer":false}

Thanks for your help!
Thanks

Comment: Note that you never use the `$paragraph` variable in your function body nor any kind of substring research function.

Comment: Also note that `$count + 1;` will do nothing, it's either `$count = $count + 1;` or `$count++`

Comment: What exactly does `$word` contain? Is it an array? It's kind of hard to understand what you're actually trying to do when looking at the code and the unclear explanation. Please post some examples, like what those variables contains and what the expected result from that would be.

Comment: $paragraph is a string of text entered by a user, $word is the keyword to be found in the $paragraph and each occurrence of it should add one to the $count variable before returning $count at the end

Comment: But your function never looks for words in that paragraph.

Comment: @arkascha sorry - I had missed a line out, have edited now to show $paragraph being used

Comment: You did not leave out a line, 
You clearly did something else in that line before. As you yourself stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a foreach loop if I get it right

```
<?php

function keyword_count($paragraph, $word)
{
    $count = substr_count($paragraph, $word);
    return $count;
}

echo keyword_count("this is text", "is");
```

Answer (score 0):

##### PHP function `substr_count()`

There is already a built-in PHP function for counting substrings: [substr_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php). If that is what you need, there is no need to implement your own function, it will probably be less performant and less error-prone.

This function, however, does not look exactly for words, but for substrings. Looking for "ban" on "We should ban bananas." would return 2 instead of 1.

Example of usage:

```php
<?php

echo substr_count("Hello world! Hello rlynch20!", "Hello"); // 2

echo PHP_EOL; // new line

echo substr_count("We should ban bananas.", "ban"); // 2 instead of 1
```

[PHP Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/X5APB)

##### Your function `substr_count_array()`

If you still want to implement your own method. Let's analyze your code:

- `$count + 1` is returning the sum, but it is not changing the value of `$count`. To increment in PHP, you could use `$count++`, `$count += 1` or `$count = $count + 1`.
- `foreach ($word as $substring)` is invalid. The first argument of `foreach` must be an array or an object. You cannot pass `$word` because it is a string.
- The `$paragraph` parameter is not being used. Without using it, your function `substr_count_array()` will not know the content of the paragraph and will never work properly.